# How to deal with intersecting documentation topics?

Tags: discussion, documentation-topics, documentation-examples

The question is arising in the Rust tag at the moment, but I can imagine that others will encounter the issue.

- We have a popular serialization framework (Serde) with its own topic
- We have requests pending for creating topics on XML serialization or JSON serialization

Both topics make sense, and I can imagine having dedicated topics for other frameworks at some point... however it is not clear how to deal with the intersection: should an example of serializing XML with Serde belong to the XML or Serde topic?

If an example can belong to multiple topics, that's great (if anyone has a how-to, I am interested); otherwise how do others handle this?

Answer (score 1):

XML is too vague of a tag to be useful in documenting something like library specific examples.

In this case, document the serialization examples in the serde tag.

I believe the best approach to use, if you were truly inclined, would be to create an entire topic consisting of several concise examples that highlight the serialization issue. Perhaps one for json, and one for xml, depending on the difference in approach or complexity.